# как установить django на сервер?

Tags: python, django, сервер, backend

Как установить django на сервер???
У меня ubuntu сервер

Comment: Почитай [эту обучалку](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/ru/django_installation/). В ней всё подробно написано. Сам по ней делал)

Comment: Но в любом случае вот так в cmd написать: python manage.py runserver

Comment: Так же, как на ubuntu десктоп или даже на винду. Какие проблемы?

Answer (score 1):

Вот хорошие мануалы для настройки серверной среды:

- [How To Set Up Django with Postgres, Nginx, and Gunicorn on Ubuntu
  16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04)
- [How To Serve Django Applications with uWSGI and Nginx on Ubuntu
  16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Gunicorn или uwsgi сложно сказать что лучше, но на мой взгляд легче настраивать gunicorn, советую его использовать.

**П.С.** при необходимости всегда можно перейти на uwsgi, если он покажет лучшие результаты при тестировании.